# Parsing and sorting NSMutableArray Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I have a UITextField with text:  9, 1, x, 1, 3, 3, y, 8

I need to remove all duplicates, remove all non-numeric characters and arrange the remaining numbers in ascending order.

So far I have:

```
-(IBAction)sortArrayPressed:(id)sender {

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[array addObject:self.textToParseTextField.text];

        NSLog([array description],nil);

}
```

The output reads:

```
Project[10176:2274463] (
    "9, 1, x, 1, 3, 3, y, 8"
)
```

Am I correct using NSMUtableArray? How do we handle parsing and sorting this sort of array which has both types Int and String? Thanks!

Comment: You need to parse the string. All you've done so far is add the single string as an element of the array. That doesn't do anything for you.

Comment: Is that one element in the array or just a mistake when making a quick example?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this, `filter` remove non-numeric string, convert to `Set` remove duplicate:

Obj-C:

```
NSString *str = @"9, 1, x, 1, 3, 3, y, 8";
NSArray* a = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
NSMutableArray *b = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *digit in a) {
    NSRange range = [digit rangeOfString:@"[0-9]" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
    if (range.location == NSNotFound) {

    } else {
        [b addObject:digit];
    }
}
b = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[NSSet setWithArray:b].allObjects];
[b sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]; //(1,3,8,9)
```

Swift:

```
let a = "9, 1, x, 1, 3, 3, y, 8".components(separatedBy: ", ")
let b = a.filter({ $0.range(of: "[0-9]", options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil })
Array(Set(b)).sorted() //["1", "3", "8", "9"]
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, the question's title mentions Objective-C, and the code in the question is in Objective-C. Posting an answer in Swift isn't helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSCharacterSet` to get all number from string after that create array from it and then use `NSSet` to get the unique object. Sort your array from set and convert array to string.

```
NSString *string = @"9, 1, x, 1, 3, 3, y, 8";
NSCharacterSet *nonDigitCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
NSArray *numberArray = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonDigitCharacterSet];

NSMutableArray *soretedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSSet setWithArray:numberArray] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                         @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"integerValue"
                                                         ascending:YES]]]];
[soretedArray removeObject:@""];
NSString *newString = [soretedArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
NSLog(@"%@",newString); //1, 3, 8, 9
```

Comment: What if `NSString *string = @"9, 1, x, 1, 3, 3, y7, 8";` and I want the Output as: **1, 3, 8, 9**?

Comment: @nayem First of all that is not suggested by **OP**, but if you have string like that then you need to first separate you string to array and then need to check individually in for loop that that object is integer or not.

Comment: Well, I get it. I just asked it for my curiosity

Comment: @nayem I know you have asked for curiosity thats why I replied you, but I have not edited answer because OP still not replied here. If he want something like that will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :**

```
 NSMutableArray *array1;
NSMutableArray *array2;
array1=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"2",@"2",@"x",@"y",@"x",@"2",@"3",@"1",@"3",@"2",@"5",@"6",@"6",nil];//example
array2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (id obj in array1)
{
    if (![array2 containsObject:obj])
    {
        [array2 addObject: obj];
    }
}
NSLog(@"new array is %@",array2);
```

**Ascending order**

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
NSArray* sortedArray = [array2 sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];                           NO;

NSLog(@"sortedArray==%@",sortedArray);

NSString * result = [sortedArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

**Remove non-numeric characters**

```
NSCharacterSet *setToRemove =
[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
NSCharacterSet *setToKeep = [setToRemove invertedSet];

NSString *newString =
[[result componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:setToKeep]
 componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSLog(@"newString=====%@",newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove duplicate from string

```
NSString *originalString = @"9, 1, x, 1, 3, 3, y, 8";
    NSMutableString *strippedString = [NSMutableString
                                       stringWithCapacity:originalString.length];

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:originalString];
    NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet
                               characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

    while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
        NSString *buffer;
        if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&buffer]) {
            [strippedString appendString:buffer];

        } else {
            [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation] + 1)];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", strippedString); 

   }
```

i hope this code will help u...